# Can I just delete mysql localhost.log file

Tags: mysql

I built a system 5 years ago. These years, localhost.log in client mysql database has been accumulated to 160G. Can I just delete this log? MySQL version is 4.0.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. IIRC, you want to use the following procedure:

1. Rename the log using `mv` or `ren` depending on the platform.
2. Use `mysqladmin flush-logs`. This should create a new `localhost.log`
3. Delete the old log that you renamed.

This procedure let's you delete the log without restarting the MySQL process.